# Как залить png изображение с помощью css

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Мне нужно заполнить картинку цветом внутри, но не снаружи с помощью css

У меня есть png

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что я делаю:

```css
img {
  background:#8abfbe;
  width:200px;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ze88p.png">
```

Что мне нужно:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [How fill png image with css](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63858963/7394871) от участника  [@rus131354](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9742738/rus131354).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/63858963/7394871

Comment: Очень интересная техника покраски png изображений, добавленных как background. Сначала прорезается маской, сделанной из того же изображения и затем заполнения цветом вырезанной области. То есть не надо никаких SVG, CSS фильтров, которые обычно используются для этих случаев.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте свой первый PNG и сделайте прозрачным только внешнюю часть, тогда вы можете использовать это изображение как маску, а также как фон для черных линий:

```css
.box {
  width:150px;
  display:inline-block;
  -webkit-mask:url(https://i.ibb.co/F5n9N7c/shirt.png) center/contain no-repeat;
          mask:url(https://i.ibb.co/F5n9N7c/shirt.png) center/contain no-repeat;
  
  background:url(https://i.ibb.co/F5n9N7c/shirt.png) center/contain no-repeat;
  background-blend-mode:darken;
}
.box:before {
  content:"";
  display:block;
  padding-top:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box" style="background-color:lightblue;"></div>
<div class="box" style="background-color:red;"></div>
<div class="box" style="background-color:lightgreen;"></div>
```

Вот изображение, используемое для лучшего понимания:

```css
img {
  background:red;
  width:150px;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.ibb.co/F5n9N7c/shirt.png">
```

Оптимизированная версия с использованием переменных CSS:

```css
.box {
  width:150px;
  display:inline-block;
  
  --m:url(https://i.ibb.co/F5n9N7c/shirt.png) center/contain no-repeat;
  -webkit-mask:var(--m);
          mask:var(--m);
  
  background:var(--m) var(--c,transparent);
  background-blend-mode:darken;
}
.box:before {
  content:"";
  display:block;
  padding-top:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box" style="--c:lightblue;"></div>
<div class="box" style="--c:red;"></div>
<div class="box" style="--c:lightgreen;"></div>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63859111/7394871) от участника  [@Temani Afif](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8620333/temani-afif).</sub>